# TensorFlow Hessian matrix is not updated after training session

Tags: python, tensorflow, hessian-matrix

I am trying to get Hessian matrix using tf.hessians function. Whereas the loss value and variables are updated after each training session, Hessian matrix values remain constant. Moreover, they does not depend on initial variable values that can be set manually. Actually, my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725228/tensorflow-gradient-and-hessian-evaluation?rq=1), that has received no answers yet. Here is the code I used for testing:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)

# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W*x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]

hess = tf.hessians(loss, [W, b])

# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    cur_hess, curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([hess, W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
    print('cur_hess', cur_hess)
```

And below is the print result:

```
W: [-0.21999997] b: [-0.456] loss: 4.0181446
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.39679998] b: [-0.49552] loss: 1.8198745
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.459616] b: [-0.4965184] loss: 1.5448234
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.48454273] b: [-0.48487374] loss: 1.4825068
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.49684232] b: [-0.4691753] loss: 1.444397
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.5049019] b: [-0.45227283] loss: 1.409699
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.5115062] b: [-0.43511063] loss: 1.3761029
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.51758033] b: [-0.41800055] loss: 1.3433373
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.523432] b: [-0.40104443] loss: 1.3113549
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
W: [-0.52916396] b: [-0.38427448] loss: 1.2801344
cur_hess [array([[60.]], dtype=float32), array([[8.]], dtype=float32)]
```

So, cur_hess is not updated, and by the way it contains only 2 elements instead of 4. How to fix it?
Also I tried to apply tf.gradients twice as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200982/how-to-compute-all-second-derivatives-only-the-diagonal-of-the-hessian-matrix), but the values are not updated as in case of tf.hessians. At the same time, tf.gradients caluculates first derivatives correctly, and they are changed after each training loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its is normal to have constant hessian in this case because,

```
loss = Σ [(Wx + b - y)^2]
```

This equation is quadratic and double derivative of quadratic is constant.

```
∂2(loss)/∂W2 = Σ 2x^2 = 2 * (1 + 4 + 9 + 16) = 60 ;(x = [1,2,3,4])

∂2(loss)/∂b2 = Σ 2 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 8 ;(4 samples with constant derivative)
```